# Call to a member function processqueue() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run this file, this file sends emails and updates tables etc (Various tasks).
But, I'm getting this error
**Fatal error: Call to a member function processqueue() on a non-object in /home/novosctn/public_html/user/cron_email_handler.php on line 14**

I've gone through various questions here but none of them helped me.
What wrong am I doing ?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

DB Structure

```
indexid(int unsigned) others
1                       xyz
2                       asa
```

The file.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnector.php';
include 'class/class.user.php';
//this file would loop through the Queued rows in the messagequeue and process them.
//first, get all the unprocessed queue.
try
{
    $statement = $conn->query("SELECT * from messagequeue where currentstatus = 'Queued'");
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    while($q = $statement->fetch())
    {
        //now process
        if($user->processqueue($q->indexid))
        {
            //$user->notifyAdmin();
            //$user->notifyUser();
            $i=2;
            //notify admin of a successful queue complete
            //notifyuser that a particular queue was not completed.
            echo $q->indexid . "was completed";
        }
        else
        {
            $i=1;
            //the particular que was not completed.
            //notify admin about this
            echo $q->indexid . "was not completed";
        }
    }
}
catch(PODException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: you may need `$user = new User()` before using the object instance for calling method.

Comment: Yeah, in the code you show, $user variable is not initiated anywhere.

Comment: Since you're using PDO, why not use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)? I.e.: `where currentstatus = ?");` or `where currentstatus = :Queued");`

Comment: Ah! That was a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.
@Fred-ii-, I'm using prepared statements for most of the work, but here, I did not use since this would be in no way vulnerable to SQL injection.